# Angular js not responding - help needed

Tags: angularjs

[This is my cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtdcn.png)

When I run my code on local host the table just flickers and disappears and also it fails to bind any data.
I'm using visual studio 2015 community and running on  .NetCOre 1.0
I'm using Angular 1.5.7
I would appreciate any help.

My angular module declaration in `apptrips.js`:

```
(function () {
  // Creating the Module
  angular.module("apptrips", []);
})();
```

[This is where the module is defined and a tripsController function is defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RgiD.png)

Below i have the following console error in browser

```
O Uncaught Error: [Sinjector:nomod] http://errors.angul angular.is:2075 aris .org/1.5.7/Siniector/nomod?p0=app-trips at angular.is:38 at angular.~is:2075 at b (angular.is:1999) at Object.module (angular.is:2073) at tripsController.is:5 at tripsController.is: 14

© ► Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularis.org/1.5. angular.is:13708 7/ng/area?p0=tripsController&pl=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefine d
at angular.is:38 at sb 
(angular.is:1885) at Qa 
(angular.is:1895) at 
angular.is:10210 at ag 
(angular.is:9331) at m 
(angular.is:9116) at g
 (angular.is:8510) at g 
(angular.is:8513) at 
angular.is:8390 at angular.is:1756
```

Comment: Any `console` messages that indicate a problem?

Comment: yes there are console errors. how can i share them with you?

Comment: Yes it would help!

Comment: @daan.desmedt check my console

Comment: Did you include the `js` file having the controller into your main index file?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working version of your example in plnkr, jsbin, ... ?

Comment: Load your scripts at bottom of the page or use `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
// do app initialization, controller definition
});`

Comment: thanks @daan.desmedt, you solved my problem

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help you! :) Please approve the answer as checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularis.org/1.5. angular.is:13708 7/ng/area?p0=tripsController&pl=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefine d
```

Error indicates that the `tripsController` is not found/loaded.

Did you include the js file having the controller into your main index file?